# Random Performance Drops and System Freezing on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, performance, freeze

My PC has been freezing or having performance dops.Basically, what happens is my mouse pointer will slow down and become skippy, or it will freeze in place and won't move for several minutes. Applications will also stop responding in the process and there have been times where my PC acted like this for almost 30 minutes. I originally thought it was the hard drive (you can find my question on that [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1262863/performance-issues-with-hdd-c-drive)) but after following the instructions in my previous help forum, and reinstalling Windows on an SSD, I'm still experiencing problems.

The only correlation that I can find is that this will sometimes will happen when I'm opening an app that uses my GPU in some way, like a game or task manager, or an app that uses GPU acceleration. But it does not happen every time and sometimes it will happen while just browsing chrome. I also get frequent notifications in Chrome saying that WebGL has stopped working.

Another theory I has was Windows because it seemed that this started happening after the fall creators update but I'm still experiencing problems even after I reinstalled Windows a few days ago. I keep task manager open so I can see my performance for my RAM, CPU, GPU, my SSD and the HDD that has been experiencing problems in the link above. When my PC starts having the performance drops, I don't see any of my resources being overused, they tend to stay below 50%.

My GPU is a GTX1050ti and I have a i5-6600k and 16gb of RAM. So my PC shouldn't be slowing down with just Chrome, task manager, Steam and Word open. After lots of troubleshooting, I don't see any problem and I don't know what to do.

Comment: "After lots of troubleshooting" - what have you tried other than loading up task manager? Have you used something like Speccy to monitor your temps? https://www.piriform.com/speccy/download  Your issue has all the hallmarks of an over-heating CPU or GPU

Comment: @spikey_richie, yes I did check my temps. My CPU max by the end of the day is 39 degrees and my GPU is around 29. in HWMonitor.